# Ancestor between two nodes

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have a question on how to Find the least common ancestor between two nodes on a binary search tree.  This is from my project, I did the following but the reviewer wants me to implement efficient solution without creating tree and adding nodes into it. I mean what I need to do to fix my code?

```
root = None

Class Node:
    #Constructor to create a new node
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    # Function to insert a new node at the beginning
    def insert_right(node, new_data):
        new_node = Node(new_data)
        node.right = new_node
        return new_node

    # Function to insert a new node at the beginning
    def insert_left(node, new_data):
        new_node = Node(new_data)
        node.left = new_node
        return new_node    

    # Function to find least common ancestor
    def lca(root, n1, n2):

        # Base case
        if root is None:
            return None

        # If both n1 and n2 are smaller than root,
        # then LCA lies on left
        if(root.data > n1 and root.data > n2):
            return lca(root.left, n1, n2)

        # if both n1 and n2 are greater than root,
        # then LCA lies on right
        if(root.data < n1 and root.data < n2):
            return lca(root.right, n1, n2) 

        return root.data

    def question4(the_matrix, the_root, n1, n2):
        global root
        root = Node(the_root)
        root.left, root.right = None, None
        node_value = 0
        tmp_right, tmp_left = None, None
        node_list = []
        for elem in the_matrix[the_root]:
            if elem:
                if(node_value>the_root):
                    node_list.append(push_right(root, node_value))
                else:
                    node_list.append(push_left(root, node_value))
            node_value += 1

        tmp_node = node_list.pop(0)
        while tmp_node != None:
            node_value = 0
            for elem in the_matrix[tmp_node.data]:
                if elem:
                    if(node_value>tmp_node.data):
                        node_list.append(push_right(tmp_node, node_value))
                    else:
                        node_list.append(push_left(tmp_node, node_value))
                node_value += 1
            if node_list == []:
                break
            else:
                tmp_node = node_list.pop(0)

        return lca(root, n1, n2)  

def main():
    global root    
    print question4([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],3, 1, 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing `lca` on the tree structure that you're defining, the reviewer wants you to use the matrix representation directly to find the LCA.

Basically, don't use a `Node` class, just use the matrix rows to understand node relationships.

Comment: Thank you @Alec, so are you saying just remove class? and remove calling Node?

Comment: Yes, and you'll need to modify the rest of the code to account for that change.

Comment: def insert_right(node, new_data):

        new_node = Node(new_data)
        node.right = new_node
        return new_node 
In this code, I used class "Node", what is the best way to modify that code?

Comment: That code shouldn't exist -- instead of creating Node objects, just use the matrix rows directly to find the LCA.

Comment: Thank you @Alec, what about on question4 function, how to adjust root.right and root.left, it is because it gives error that says "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'left'"

Comment: Right, `left` no longer exists once you get rid of the Node class. Instead of using `.left`, you need to access the row of the matrix directly to understand what the left child is.

Comment: Okay, I changed that, but in question4 function I am calling push_right and push_left. What do I do for these two functions?